# Deafult value of log field in apache

Tags: apache

I want to replace default value in apache log field, if value is not coming.
e.g. if i have mentioned %q for query string in apache2.conf, but in any particular log line the query string is not there. I want to replace that blank space with say '*'. Is it possible to do while mentioning the apache format?

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 different LogFormats. These formats can be the same except in first you use `%q` (it would be used when query string presents) and in second you use `*` insted of `%q` (it would be used with no-query-string request). For example:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %q" first
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t *" second
```

Then you have to tell Apache to set environment variable according to query string presence in request using `If` like:

```
<If "-z %{QUERY_STRING}">
    SetEnv noquery
</If>
```

And then you need to define 2 different CustomLog directives one for each situaition. But both CustomLog's must point to one log file. Like:

```
CustomLog "logs/access_log" first env=!noquery
CustomLog "logs/access_log" second env=noquery
```

If you have query string in request - `noquery` environment variable is not set and Apache uses first `CustomLog` directive to write log to.

If request has no query string - `noquery` environment variable is being set and Apache uses second `CustomLog` directive to write log to.

Comment: Useful trick share by you! but making this type of changes for every format field is not practical I think . There could be more  field with missing value, I want to replace them also with *. Then this technique would be little difficult.